# ASME “text-only” submission in LaTeX

Tags: latex

We are submitting a journal paper to ASME Journals of Mechanisms and Robotics for the first time. The manuscript is prepared in LaTeX. In the final submission, it is required that we submit "text-only" file along with the final PDF.

> II. TEXT-ONLY FILE(S)
>
> 1. The text-only file, Word or LaTex, should include the following items in order:
>
> 1.1. paper title
>
> 1.2. author(s) info (affiliation, address, email)
>
> 1.3. abstract
>
> 1.4. text: single column and double spaced
>
> 1.5. reference section (ASME requires a numerical format, e.g., [1], [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50904/how-can-i-remove-the-figures-from-a-draft-of-my-document), etc.)
>
> 1.6. table caption list
>
> 1.7. figure caption list
>
> 1.8. tables, each on separate page
>
> 1.9. footers  containing page number

[ASME guidelines](http://journaltool.asme.org/Help/AuthorHelp/WebHelp/JournalsHelp.htm)

If someone who has submitted to ASME before can answer what exactly are they expecting from LaTeX users, it shall be of great help.

1. Are we just supposed to upload the LaTeX document as is and the requirement is more directed towards Word users?
2. Am I supposed to remove all the figures? That would mess up the references. In order to correct that I shall have to manually add the reference numbers to figure! I tried options such as [How can I remove the figures from draft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50904/how-can-i-remove-the-figures-from-a-draft-of-my-document) and gobbling the \includegraphics command, but in vain.
3. Do I have to manually type the figure caption list? As deleting the figures would remove all the references and \listoffigures wouldn't work.
4. What exactly does this requirement mean?

   > 1.9. footers containing page number

Regards.

Comment: You should contact the journal directly. Only they can give a definite answer.

Comment: Well I have mailed them. Hope to receive a reply soon.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted the ASME staff and they said

> "You can submit the LaTeX files with the figures embedded and we will accommodate."

I guess that makes life easier and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not made any ASME submissions, the following information might be of some use to you.

> Am I supposed to remove all the figures? That would mess up the references.

Yes. But only from the `tex` file. You must include the figures (only as EPS or TIFF as per ASME guidelines) as separate files. You can do this without adversely affecting references by adding the `[demo]` option when including the `graphicx` package.

`\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`

It is the label you add inside the `figure` environment that counts in the list of figures. There would be no error even if you don't include any image (like using `\includegraphics`) inside the environment. Although the page numbers may vary, the actual list would remain intact.

> 1.9. footers containing page number

This is not for LaTeX users to worry about. If the class file provided by the journal is coded properly, it should take care of this by itself.

> The full contents of the paper must be submitted in the PDF file.

The above line is also included in the ASME guidelines. I suppose it is the the PDF of how you intend it to be. This may submit the necessary figures as per your liking. However, I think you may submit both PDFs, one with figures `YourTitle_(with_figs).pdf`, and one without `YourTitle_(without_figs).pdf` and intimate this to the editor for clarification.

Comment: The option `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` did work to remove the figure, but I had to retain the caption. As we are supposed to prepare a separate list for the captions, I am not sure if it is to be retained in the main text. I shall get back once I hear from the publishers.